# Adding drag and drop support to Jtree

Tags: jtree, treenode

i want to add drag and drop support to my JTree application

i hav a created a custom DefaultMutableTreeNode subclass

hav a default TreeCellRenderer

what all things do i need to add and where?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drag and Drop nodes in JTree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588109/drag-and-drop-nodes-in-jtree)

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is to
 1. Call tree.setDragEnabled(true)
 2. set tree.transferHandler

There's a tutorial at:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html

You create a subclass of TransferHandler where you implement

```
canImport(JComponent comp, DataFlavor[] transferFlavors)
```

and

```
importData(JComponent comp, Transferable t)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this also useful

https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/adding_drop_support_to_jtree