# Drag and drop between 2 Jtrees

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtree

In my application I have 2 JTree controls in a JPanel. How can I transfer data between them, so that the items from the source tree are removed.

Answer (score 1):

Write appropriate subclasses of `javax.swing.TransferHandler` for both trees. Use `TransferHandler.MOVE` as the source action. Override `exportDone()` and see if the action includes the MOVE flag. If so, delete the object represented by the `Transferable`.

Also see this question: [Adding drag and drop support to Jtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526291/adding-drag-and-drop-support-to-jtree)