# JTree Drag and Drop in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtree

How can I add drag and drop support to a JTree using the Netbeans GUI editor? Just something simple, like rearranging the nodes in the tree.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drag and Drop nodes in JTree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588109/drag-and-drop-nodes-in-jtree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the Netbeans editor, you're going to have to delve into the code to get this to work.  I suggest reading the following as they should help greatly.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html

http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip97.html

Comment: Yes, this is what I had to do. I had to create some custom code. This link was especially helpful: http://www.coderanch.com/t/346509/GUI/java/JTree-drag-drop-inside-one