# JTree Drag and Drop: drag nodes with its childs

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtree

I would like to add drag and drop feature to my `JTree`. 
I have tried to run example from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588109/drag-and-drop-nodes-in-jtree). It works but it works only on last leaves in tree, not on nodes that contain some childs. I have also looked on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526291/adding-drag-and-drop-support-to-jtree).

I have defined canImport and importData methods, and also have set setDragEnabled(true). I just cannot drag nodes also with its childs.

How to edit example from first link to drag also nodes with its childs? As I understand correctly, I should set DataFormat instance, to set what types should be dragged. 
Can anybody help?